# Theoretical resistance of a wire

Tags: resistance, wire

In theory, What is the resistance of a wire? I have heard that it is 1Ω before, is that correct? in a standard PCB circuit, should I be more worried about the theoretical resistance of a wire, or of the real-world equivalent resistance?

Theory, defined as Circuit Analyzation , primarily, Ohms law.

Comment: The resistance of a wire depends on the shape, length, and material of the wire as well as environmental conditions.

Comment: Which theory? The theoretical resistance of an ideal wire is 0. We can also use the theory to calculate the resistance of real wires, but you have to know the size and material.

Comment: So how would I do Ohms law on a resistor with 0 resistance? I = 5v / 0 ohms? @user253751

Comment: you've got it the other way around, V = 5A * 0 ohms

Comment: Ok. Yeah V=IR, but how would I do the other ohms-law algebraic equivalents? I mean, how do I divide by zero? @user253751

Comment: How do you do the speed-law algebraic relationships? Asking how much current goes through an ideal wire when there's a voltage across it is like asking: if I drive a [rock](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTOwMeimSl4) (speed=0) for 5 miles, how long does it take me? Or, if I have a teleporter that takes me anywhere instantly, and I drive it for 5 minutes, how far have I gone?

Comment: Why would you divide by zero?

Comment: Say, using ohms law, I wanted to get the current from a point in my circuit schematic. And I wanted to do it across a wire with no resistors. How would I do that? I cant do I = voltage / 0... @Transistor

Comment: @User1 Say, using the speed law, I wanted to get the speed someone traveled based on the time it took them. And they used a teleporter. How would I do that? I can't do speed = distance / 0 ...

Comment: Your question about ideal wire of 0 ohms is like mathematical question "what is 1/0?", even math says it is undefined. Same is the answer for your question.

Comment: The voltage across an ideal wire is always assumed to be zero. Ohm's law will be used on other circuit elements such as resistors, but not on the wire. Those other elements will act to limit the current. If you short out an ideal voltage source with an ideal wire, that is one of those impossible situations. Like an irresistible force and an immovable object.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on what theory you want.  An ideal wire has zero resistance.  But only superconductors achieve that.

For real wires,

> R = l ρ / A

where l is the length of the wire, ρ is the resistivity of the material, and A is the cross-sectional area of the wire.

Note that ρ is temperature-dependent.

Answer (score 4):

From the comments:

> Say, using ohms law, I wanted to get the current from a point in my circuit schematic. And I wanted to do it across a wire with no resistors. How would I do that? I cant do I = voltage / 0.

You consider the current through the complete circuit, not just the 0 ohm part. You'll have a voltage source and the resistance of the rest of the circuit will determine the current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSkrmR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Then, using that value of current, you can use Ohm's law to calculate the voltage drop across the 0 Ω point as
*V = IR = I × 0 = 0* V.

Regarding the other part of your question,

> What is the resistance of a wire? I have heard that it is 1Ω before, is that correct?

... I am reminded of the rhetorical question, "How long is a piece of string?" If I said that I had heard that it was 1 metre what would your reaction be?

Answer (score 0):

> > Say, using ohms law, I wanted to get the current from a point in my circuit schematic. And I wanted to do it across a wire with no resistors. How would I do that? I cant do I = voltage / 0

You can't.   You do this by inserting a non-zero ohm resistor there and measuring the voltage across it.  This is called a "current sense resistor".   You choose a value small enough such that it has little or no effect on the rest of the circuit.   A value of 1-ohm is very commonly used because it makes the math easier. (That's probably where you got your the '1-ohm' rule).  If you use 1-ohm, then the voltage measured is exactly the same as the current measured.  i.e. if you measured 45mV on this resistor, it means there is 45mA flowing through it.

If your circuit can't tolerate 1-ohm, you could use a 0.1 ohm, and then you'd have 1mV = 10mA, etc...